# Como hacer que al seleccionar una opcion en un combobox me vuelva a restaurar

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hola buenas tardes cuento con un combobox el cual necesito que cuando yo seleccione por ejemplo placa grúa, placa canasta, placa moto, placa vehículo.
y llene la placa en el input text luego le doy subir a la placa y me restaure a la opción principal que es la primer opción que esta en blanco

```
<select class="form-control" id="tipo_vehiculo">
               <option value=""></option>
                <option value="grua">placa grua</option>
                <option value="canasta">placa canasta</option>
                <option value="moto">placa moto</option>
                <option value="vehiculo">placa vehiculo</option>                 
                </select>
                <em></em>
                <br>
  <center><input type="text"  class="control-label"  id="placa" disabled></center>
  <input type="button" value="Subir placa"  id="btncreartipovehiculo" />
```

Comment: ¿Ha que te requieres al decir "Restaure a la opción principal que es esta"?

Comment: cuando le de con el boton enviar me muestre desde 0 la opcion  <option value=""></option>

Comment: Te recomiendo que le pongas un value a la primera opcion para que sea mas facil identificarlo, te dejo un ejemplo funcional https://jsfiddle.net/32y4h0at/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes seleccionar el primer elemento con cambiarle la propiedad selected, en caso de que tu select o combo no sea multiple puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<input type="button" value="Subir placa"  id="btncreartipovehiculo" onclick="subir()" />
  <script>
    var subir = function(){
        var combo = document.querySelector("#tipo_vehiculo");
        combo.querySelector("option").setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    }
  </script>
```

Si tu selects es multiple puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
 <input type="button" value="Subir placa"  id="btncreartipovehiculo" onclick="subir()" />
  <script>
    var subir = function(){
        var combo = document.querySelector("#tipo_vehiculo");
        var options = combo.querySelectorAll("option:checked");
        options.forEach(function(item){
            item.selected = false;
        });
        combo.querySelector('option').selected = true;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: no me sirvio amigo :(

Comment: A ver el codigo lo probe con el mismo codigo que pusistes de ejemplo, explicame mejor que fue lo ke no te funciono, que esperabas realmente que sucediera????

Comment: A mi entender querias luego de seleccionar una opcion de tu select y dar click sobre el boton de subir placa deberia seleccionar el primer elemento del select. Era eso????

Comment: exacto amigo mandarlo a la opcion  que esta vacia

Comment: Y que sucede ??? porque yo como ya explique lo probe y marca la primera opción. Si quieres salir de la duda dentro de <option value=''></option> Ponle un texto para que veas como lo deja marcado cuando haces click

Comment: use el mismo codigo amigo pero no me hace nada C':

Comment: Mira monte un JsFiddle para que veas que me funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/74s3fowu/

Comment: Amigo como lo colocaria en el javascript que te deje en  jsFiddle en la parte de css https://jsfiddle.net/74s3fowu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Agregar un `EventListener` al click de tu botón, al hacer click obtén el `ComboBox` y el `selectedIndex` colócalo en `-1` así selecciona limpia la selección.

```js
document.getElementById("btncreartipovehiculo").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  document.getElementById("tipo_vehiculo").selectedIndex = -1;
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="tipo_vehiculo">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="grua">placa grua</option>
  <option value="canasta">placa canasta</option>
  <option value="moto">placa moto</option>
  <option value="vehiculo">placa vehiculo</option>                 
</select>
<em></em>
<br />
<center>
  <input type="text" class="control-label" id="placa" disabled />
</center>
  <input type="button" value="Subir placa" id="btncreartipovehiculo" />
```